# How to remove Messages app for SMS from Android 10 Wiko View 4 phone?

Tags: root-access, system-apps, default-applications, android-10, instant-messaging

I want to remove the default messages application called Messages which handles sms sending and receiving from my Wiko View 4 Android 10 device.

The reason I am wishing to uninstall this app is that I deem some of the content in this app inappropriate.

Can I install SuperSU or something to root the device and then remove this app?

Is there some other way to remove it?

Is there a way to remove it at all?

When I click on it I can only remove it from my home screen, but cannot uninstall it because the uninstall option to drag the app to in the screen is missing (only the remove place where to drag the icon appears).

If I remove the Messages app from the home screen, I still can see it in the list, if apps, when I scroll up on the home screen with my fingers to see all apps.

But I don't want this app anywhere on my phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can root you phone and remove the messages app but i warn you that removing system apps is very risky. Why not just disable it because removing it completely you might regret it greatly afterwards

1. Go to settings
2. Go to apps or app manager
3. Go to all apps (differs from phone to phone)
4. Search for the message app tap on it and then disable it.